# How do I connect to anything BUT localhost?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am making a webapp that allows users to connect to their own database and run various commands. How do I make it so that they can connect to anything BUT localhost (I don't want them messing with my database)? I do need to have localhost access for my website backend stuff so I can't simply disable it in one of the config files.

I am using Golang if that makes any difference.

They would be connecting to their own remote hosts and not a database connected to localhost.

Comment: Don't give them the password?

Comment: With enough attempts they could guess it

Comment: "To anything but localhost" - why not check that in your application?

Comment: PIck a password that doesn't suck.  Enough time would be billions of years and the CPU and network load would be hard to miss.  They can't hashcat it, it would have to go through the PostgreSQL machinery (plus the webapp in front of that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `pg_hba.conf` entries that reject connections from Unix sockets and all local IP addresses.

Comment: but that would cut my connection off that I need, no?

Comment: That's pretty much catch-22 then.